# Overloading __set to use whichever is in it's class

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class, magic-methods

Is there a way to have the __set method in the abstract class be executed if the variable being changed is declared in the abstract class and run a different __set if the variable being changed belongs to the class extending the abstract class. I'm sure I'm going about this the wrong way, any help would be appreciated it.

```
abstract class abstract_class {
    protected $protected_var;

    function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "abstract __set";
    }
}

class regular_class extends abstract_class {
    private $temp;

    function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "regular __set";
    }
}

$class = new regular_class();
$class->protected_var = "value";
```

In the above example, I would want "abstract __set" to be outputted instead of "regular __set" being outputted.

Comment: Not implement the method in the extended class

Comment: What if the extended class has variables that I would like to set using __set or is that not possible?

Comment: What you want is what @JohnSmith have posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Base
{
    protected $a = "a";

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "base";
    }
}

class Child extends Base
{
    private $b = "b";
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if (property_exists(get_parent_class(), $name))
            parent::__set($name, $value);
        else
            echo "child";
    }
}

$obj = new Child();

$obj->a = 1;
$obj->b = 1;
```

here is solution

remember, always when you create child of any class and want to overload __set, you need 1st to check if property is in parent class otherwise it won't work properly

Comment: I'd post the same exemple. :)

Comment: I've changed it, because forgot about something xd